# Is there a way to syntactically simulate empty constraints with GHC < 7.8.1?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

## TL;DR

Is there a way to simulate empty constraints with GHC < `7.8.1`?  Something
similar to

```
{-# LANGUAGE NullaryTypeClasses #-}
class HasCallStack
instance HasCallStack
```

so that e.g.

```
foo :: HasCallStack => Int -> Int
```

is technically the same as

```
foo :: Int -> Int
```

## Motivation

GHC 8.0.1 introduces `HasCallStack` as:

```
HasCallStack = (?callStack :: CallStack)
```

For a compatibility shim I want to define `HasCallStack` for all versions of
GHC back to `7.0.1`.

For versions of GHC that have support for implicit parameter based call stacks,
`HasCallStack` should be functionally equivalent to what we have in GHC 8.0.1.

For versions of GHC that lack support for implicit parameter based call stacks
(that is all versions of GHC < `7.10.2`), `HasCallStack` should be functionally
equivalent to the empty constraint.

For completeness, here is the code that we could use if we only care about GHC
`7.8.1` and later:

```
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,8,1)
type HasCallStack = (?callStack :: CallStack)
#else
class HasCallStack
instance HasCallStack
#endif
```

Is there a way to make this work for older versions of GHC?

For reference, I'll add my current solution as an answer.  But I'd love to get
input on other ways to tackle this.

Comment: I don't have any ghc version older than 7.10 - does `type HasCallStack = (() :: Constraint)` work? You need `-XConstraintKinds` and `import GHC.Exts (Constraint)`

Comment: `type HasCallStack = (() :: Constraint)` works for GHC versions back to GHC 7.4.1.  That's nice!

Comment: You could also use `#define HasCallStack ()` - this would avoid `ConstraintKinds` and would support more versions of ghc. `()` is a valid constraint even in Haskell 98.

Comment: I guess this works, but it may be a little bit heavy weight.  AFAIK, this would require `install-includes` for the cabal package to install an include file that contains the CPP define, e.g. `callstack.h`.  The user would then need to enable `CPP` and `#include "callstack.h"`.  Or do you think there is an easier way?

Comment: I doubt it, but I wouldn't do such a thing for user facing/library code. The most portable thing would be to use a regular class instead of a nullary one: `class HasCallStack x; instance HasCallStack ()` or `type HasCallStack x = (?callstack :: Callstack)`. You have to write `HasCallStack ()` but it will really work with any compiler version without CPP hacks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any way to support the exact same syntax we have in GHC
`8.0.1`.  However, it's possible to optionally add a constraint by using a type
synonym and `Rank2Types`.  The following code works for all versions of GHC
back to `7.0.1`.

```
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,8,1)
type HasCallStack a = (?callStack :: CallStack) => a
#else
type HasCallStack a = a
#endif
```

The example from your question

```
foo :: HasCallStack => Int -> Int
```

becomes

```
foo :: HasCallStack(Int -> Int)
```

Note that this is quite robust.  I haven't encountered any situation where this would not work, it e.g. even works when `foo` has other constraints or when `foo` is a `class` method.

Comment: `RankNTypes` should only be required for (effectively) using `HasCallStack` on the left side of an arrow, right?

Comment: From what I have tried you need `Rank2Types`/`RankNTypes` for defining `HasCallStack`.  In modules that merely use `HasCallStack` you only need `FlexibleContexts`.